# Removing unused CSS - Tailwind

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I want to deploy my **Laravel 8 app** with **Tailwind**  using the free tier on **Heroku**.

I have finished setting up the *tailwind.config.js* file. However, I am kinda lost on how I would compile my CSS with `NODE_ENV` set to `production`. Also, is this something I should do locally ? Lastly, I have read that it is recommended removing unused styles only in production.

Any hint on how I would exactly do this with my current setup, or info that would clear up my confusion can really be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You have 2 approaches, either you run `npm run prod` and then upload the final `public/*` compiled files into your git and in the server you deploy that, or you do not add those files to git and you run the same command in your server. You have to run `npm run prod` to automatically have `NODE_ENV = production`. Follow TailwindCSS [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#removing-unused-css) about purging your CSS, it works awesome !

Comment: So basically, I can just run `npm run prod` and directly push it onto the server (heroku) without pushing it in my actual repo (github repo) ? Yes, I'm following TailwindCSS docs, just a bit confused on purging part. But I do enjoy TailwindCSS  and will definitely use it in my future projects. Thank you for your answer! @matiaslauriti